# Matlab: How to plot only the top portion of 3D bar plot

Tags: matlab

A fragment of my data is as follows.

```
nw, wl, F1
8, 8, 0.9229
8, 16, 0.9206
8, 32, 0.9312
16, 8, 0.907
16, 16, 0.9263
16, 32, 0.9141
32, 8, 0.9443
32, 16, 0.9255
32, 32, 0.9318
```

I am currently using Matlab 3D column bar plot to visualize the data. However, as the z values are mostly centered around 0.9, I would like to show only the top portion of the bars.

My code is as follows:

```
fid = fopen('testdata.csv', 'rt');
C = textscan(fid, '%s %s %f', 'Delimiter',',');
fclose(fid);

%# correctly reshape the data, and extract x/y labels
num = 6;
nw = reshape(C{1},num,[]); nw = nw(1,:); %x
wl = reshape(C{2},num,[]); wl = wl(:,1); %y
Z = reshape(C{3},num,[]);

%# plot 3D bars
bar3(Z)

xlabel('num walks'), ylabel('walk length'), zlabel('F1-Score')
set(gca, 'XTickLabel',nw, 'YTickLabel',wl, 'zlim', [85 100])
```

I tried to achieve this by using zlim in set(). However doing so results in none of the bars displaying.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, when setting Zlim, try [0.85 1]. You are currently zooming way above your data